# Load and Execute an javascript function in an External JS file using Node.js

Tags: php, jquery, node.js, web-services, asmx

I'd like to load and execute a Javascript function in external Javascript file using Node.js and similarly retrieve back with desired result after execution. Is it possible/not possible? If not, any other alternatives.

Any help regarding this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can load another JS file as a module using Node.js module system and function `require`. There's quite good description of how to do it in Node.js documentation, take a look int this [page](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_modules).

Basically you have to load your external file calling function `require` and passing path to that file:

```
var externalFunction = require('./path/to/external/file')`;
```

but to make this work you have to export that function by writing something like

```
module.exports = functionToExport;
```

in your external file, where `functionToExport` is the name of the function which you want to use.